# Incorrect paystub dates for payment received a year later

Tags: united-states, background-check, w2

Some background:

I worked few early months of 2020 for my now-former employer. Because of the pandemic, everything was closed down by the late March. I never received my paycheck (and the paystub) for the last week of my then job.

Later, in 2021, I asked the employer (the former employer by then) to provide me the paycheck for the unpaid work. They did. However, their paystub had incorrect dates. Instead of the actual "2020/March/Last-week", the paystub had "2021/January/First-week" as the days I worked. I asked them about the incorrect dates, but I never received any response. (Also, I received W-2 for 2021 instead of the corrected W-2 for 2020. I never worked for them during 2021).

I am applying where I **need to provide accurate** employment dates for all my previous jobs.
Should the employment date be the actual dates I worked, Or the dates as reflected on the paystub?

Comment: Though the answer may seem obvious to some, I can see the question being valuable to someone caught trying to navigate the corporate bureaucracy of a new organisation, and stuck deciding the right thing to do. It doesn't seem specific to the person or org, either.

Comment: @hilmar they didn't commit tax fraud If the 2020 W-2 matches what checks they issued in 2020.

Comment: @Hilmar No! Wrong! Individual wages in the US operate on a strictly cash-accounting basis. They are taxed when *actually received* - not when the hours are worked. The situation described is proper (tax-wise only; the employer may have other liability for paying the wages so extremely late). Please delete your incorrect comment.

Comment: Sorry, I got my assumptions wrong. Comment deleted

Comment: thank you for the comments. I am curious if someone can point me out why the question was downvoted. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, I received W-2 for 2021 instead of the corrected W-2 for 2020. I
> never worked for them during 2021.

They paid you wages in 2021. Therefore they need to send the money they withheld to the IRS and the state tax authority.

It is normal to be paid in 2021 for hours worked in 2020. In the US the first paycheck received in year X has some or all of the hours from the previous year. In my case I am paid 2x a month. The 2nd pay period each month always ends on the last day of the month. That means my hours for the last part of December are paid in January. Because the W-2 ends in December the late December hours appear in the W-2 for the following year.

They can't go back and modify the W-2 for 2020 because they didn't pay you in 2020. If a check they issued in 2020 was lost and they were issuing a replacement in 2021 the numbers would have already been in the 2020 W-2.

Check your pay stubs for 2020 and compare it to the W-2 for 2020.

> I am applying where I need to provide accurate employment dates for
> all my previous jobs. Should the employment date be the actual dates I
> worked, Or the dates as reflected on the paystub?

Use the last day you physically did work for them. It is normal to have the last paycheck appear the following month. I worked for one company who paid unused PTO using the regular pay periods, so it could stretch out for more than a month.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Does it matter if the paystub has incorrect hours? (The paystub says hours worked are in 2021 instead of 2020. Exact number of hours are correct though)

Answer (score 5):

> I am applying where I need to provide accurate employment dates for
> all my previous jobs. Should the employment date be the actual dates I
> worked, Or the dates as reflected on the paystub?

Since the accurate dates are the dates you actually worked, supply those.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Does it matter if the paystub has incorrect hours? (The paystub says hours worked are in 2021 instead of 2020. Exact number of hours are correct though)

Answer (score 4):

> Should the employment date be the actual dates I worked ?

Yes.

Call HR, accounting department, or even your former manager and ask them to make a correction.

A phone call is generally faster to get a response than an email. But, you can try both at the same time if you want to. However, they won't automatically send private info such as paycheck stub to an unverified email account such as gmail, etc...

Be persistent and eventually someone will pick up the phone to answer you.

Comment: Personally, I'd send the email, and I'd immediately follow it up with a phone call. This way, there is a time stamped paper trail.

Comment: I called them but unfortunately the company is sold (under new name) by the time I received my W2. I did not realize the paystub dates were incorrect until much later. The new owner (although the management is the same) did not respond to my further inquiries.